# Escape tags in HTML

Tags: html, tags, escaping

What are escape tags in HTML?

Are they `&#34;`  `&#60;`  `&#62;` to represent `"` `<` `>`?
And how do these work?

Is that hex, or what is it?

How is it made, and why aren't they just the characters themselves?

Answer (score 49):

Here are some common [entities](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp). You do not need to use the full code - there are common aliases for frequently used entities. For example, you can use < and > to indicate less than and greater than symbols. & is ampersand, etc.

EDIT: That should be - `&lt; &gt; and &amp;`

EDIT: Another common character is `&nbsp` which is often used to represent tabs in `<code>` segments

Answer (score 37):

**How do these work?**

Anything `&#num;` is replaced with character from ASCII table, matching that `num`.

**Is that hex, or what is it?**

It's not hex, the number represents characters number in decimal in ASCII table. Check out [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Check Dec and HTML columns.

**Why aren't they just the characters themselves?**

Look at this example:

```
<div>Hey you can use </div> to end div tag!</div>
```

It would mess up the interpreter. It's a bad example, but you got the idea.

**Why you can't use escape characters like in programming languages?**

I don't have exact answer to that. But html same as xml is a markup language and not programming language and answer probably lies within history of how markup languages become what they are now.

Comment: I think he means, why don't you just use \< to escape <, as in strings in many programming languages?

Comment: NAh, I was just meaning why I couldn't use say < instead of the ascii.  But I your example really explains. it.  I guess it would confuse the browser.

Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not hex, it's decimal. Hex equivalent is &#x3c; But one usually uses &lt; (less-than) for < and &gt; for > instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete reference of html entities:

[Complete HTML Entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

It is use for correct character formatting

HTML has a set of special characters which browsers recognize as part of the HTML language itself. For example, browsers know that when they encounter a < character in the HTML code, they are to interpret it as a beginning of a tag. > is one of an example of reserved character. Therefore use html character to avoid any problem and for correct practice also

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is nearly 10 years old. You may want to look at some more recent questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest

Answer (score 0):

Those escapes are decimal ascii escapes. You can see the values [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).  Take a look at the HTML column.