# how to write html code and stop it from being executed ?? so that I can share a code as if its normal text or string?

Tags: html

it's simple html tag related problem, I guess.

I want to share few lines of code in my blog, and I want to write `<h1> heading</h1>`. visitors must see `<h1> heading </h1>`, and not just **heading**. do I need to use JavaScript for this, please help me with this problem.

Comment: are you looking for [<code>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape tags in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692123/escape-tags-in-html)

Comment: no, say I wrote <h1> heading </h1> in an index.html file. on web it will look like just heading. I want it to look as <h1> heading </h1>

Comment: Just searching on SO you can find a lot of [answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+display+raw+HTML+code+on+an+HTML+page+site%253Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: For HTML Tags, you need to escape them either manually or using some JS library. Even if you use `pre` or `code` tags it won't work, escaping is the only option. Another simple way of doing it is by adding it using JavaScript with `parentELement.textContent = "<h1>Hello</h1>"`

Comment: One could also use a `<textarea>`, disable it and style it accordingly how you want it. Then you don't have to escape everything all the time and don't need any libraries. Bit whacky but it's working

Answer (score 1):

you can use HTML Entities like &lt , &gt

```
<h1>&lt;h1&gt;heading;/h1&gt;</h1>
```

and this link may help you https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Escape the Characters using HTML Entities or Using a JS Library
2. Dynamically add the content using JavaScript `textContent` Property.

Here is a Sample code using both:

```js
const codeSnippet = document.getElementById("codeSnippet");
codeSnippet.textContent = "<h1>Heading</h1>";
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Escaping:</p>
  <code>
    &lt;h1&gt;Heading&lt;/h1&gt;
  </code>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Dynamically added usisng JS:</p>
  <code id="codeSnippet"></code>
</div>
```